# How can I call a web service and pass parameters using the URL

Tags: asp.net, web-services, url

How can I call a ASP .NET web service and pass parameters using the URL?

For example, the URL for the service is like,

`http://[localhost]:31856/MySystem/MyAPI.asmx?op=getHeight`

I need to pass two parameters a and b, I tried

`http://[localhost]:31856/MySystem/MyAPI.asmx?op=getHeight?a=254&b=1`

But failed.

Please advice.

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 10):

If you need to pass more than one parameter, use this format `param1=value1&param2=value2` and so on.So your link should be:

```
http://[localhost]:31856/MySystem/MyAPI.asmx/AnyMethodName?op=getHeight&a=254&b=1
```

You need a method like this.This method returns a list of strings,its just for demonstration.

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<string> AnyMethodName(string op, string a, string b)
    {
       //Do whatever you want, get answer
        return (ans.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Ashwin, It does not show an out put so how can I know if the underlyinging function executed successfully?

Comment: Look at kad1r answer, you need a WebMethod, to process these queries and url like this http://[localhost]:31856/MySystem/MyAPI.asmx/getVariables?op=getHeight&a=254&b=1

Comment: I understand, my situation is a bit different, I need to execute the web service purely from the URL (for performance testing) and get the output.

Comment: What output do you need and what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: My method returns a string, the thing is when I execute it from the URL with the parameters is there a possibility to view the output?

Comment: My test simulator only accepts URLs and the problem is that I need to test the performance of this web service using it.

Comment: I don't know about your test unit but if you view the service on your browser, then there is a option to invoke your method, whatever it is, which then returns xml data, you can test it that way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13002/discussion-between-ashwin-singh-and-dafadil)

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and I needed to add the following in my webconfig inside the system.web -tag:

```
<webServices>
<protocols>
<add name="HttpGet" />
</protocols>
</webServices>
```

The rest was pretty much like already mentioned (using the example from Ashwin's answer, just removed the op-parameter)

```
   [WebMethod]
    public List<string> AnyMethodName(string a, string b)
    {
       //Do whatever you want, get answer
        return (ans.ToList());
    }
```

After that I was able to call the webservice with the following (removed the op-parameter again):

```
http://localhost/MySystem/MyAPI.asmx/AnyMethodName?a=254&b=1
```

Comment: This was the fix for me!  I actually enabled both get and post: <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet"/>
            <add name="HttpPost"/>
        </protocols>
    </webServices>

Answer (score 4):

Change the second `?` to `&`.  If you look at the page rendered by `http://[localhost]:31856/MySystem/MyAPI.asmx`, it will show you how to call it as an `HTTP GET`.

Comment: Thanks jonnyGold, it is not giving me any error now but it does not show an out put, how can I know if the underlyinging function executed successfully?

Comment: Try pointing [SOAP UI](http://www.soapui.org/) at it.  It is a good "foreign" web service debugging tool.

Answer (score 2):

It's not like that.
You have to declare the parameters in function.
For example here is a little example:

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] getVariables(string sop, string sgsm)
{ // do what you want ... }
```

Then when you call it

```
WebReference.Service1 service = new WebReference.Service1();
service.getVariables("foo", "blabla");
```

Answer (score 0):

**Follow Below Steps**

**Step 1:**  Click on Add Service Reference and add reference of service .
It creates reference in a partial class to the service and all the methods which you need to call the service under the project namespace.

**Step 2:** Add the same class in using ..

**Step 3:** Browse the class file generated under the service reference and get the name of it .

**Step 4:** Create a client like `new Service1SoapClient("Service1Soap");` and then use the service as Method . You can pass the parameter (if requires) like the way you pass while calling one method from another .